# Case insensitive URLs with Struts and Convention plugin

Tags: java, struts2

How can we have case insensitive URLs with Struts and Convention plugin?

Request to `www.somelocation.com/ABC-DEF` should return same response as  `www.somelocation.com/abc-def`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should consider URL rewriting as URLs are case sensitive.

The following link should help, in particular the Flags section - NC (case insensitive).

[URL Rewriting for Beginners](http://www.addedbytes.com/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/)

Or, if this is too complex in your case as home comments below, you could consider putting a servlet filter in front of the HTTP requests processing. The filter will take care to modify the request `toLowerCase()` or `toUpperCase()` and then in your web app URL mappings you need to be always consistent (with `toLowerCase()` or `toUpperCase()` URLs).

Comment: This would become fairly complex if you have a dynamic web application defining an 'unknown' number of URLs (actions) and thus an unknown number of URL permutations.